# Is it safe to send a pointer to a CriticalSection Function? C++

Tags: c++, critical-section

I have some statics I use to check if a thread is running, and if the program wants to / can close.

Normally I would create a seperate function for each variable like so:

```
static              CCriticalSection crit_sec;

static bool         static_thread_a_closed = false;
static bool         static_thread_b_closed = false;
static bool         static_prog_closing = false;

static void Set_thread_a_Val(bool set_to)
{
    crit_sec.Lock();
    static_thread_a_closed = set_to;
    crit_sec.Unlock();
};

static bool Get_thread_a_Val()
{
    bool ret;

    crit_sec.Lock();
    ret = static_thread_a_closed;
    crit_sec.Unlock();

    return ret;
};

// etc etc for the others...

void thread_a::Do()
{
    //code
    Set_thread_a_Val(false);
}

void MainDlg::OnClose()
{
    //code..
    while(Get_thread_a_Val()) // ... wait
    //code..
}
```

I am wondering if it would be 'safe' to do this with pointers like so:

```
static              CCriticalSection crit_sec;

static bool         static_thread_a_closed = false;
static bool         static_thread_b_closed = false;
static bool         static_prog_closing = false;

static void Set_Bool_Val(bool* val, bool set_to)
{
    crit_sec.Lock();
    *val = set_to;
    crit_sec.Unlock();
};

static bool Get_Bool_Val(bool* val)
{
    bool ret;

    crit_sec.Lock();
    ret = *val;
    crit_sec.Unlock();

    return ret;
};

void thread_a::Do()
{
    //code
    Set_Bool_Val(&static_thread_a_closed, false);
}

void MainDlg::OnClose()
{
    //code..
    while(Get_Bool_Val(&static_thread_a_closed)) // ... wait
    //code..
}
```

Is the memory actually accessed when it is passed, so this will fail?

Or is it simply pass the address, meaning this would be ok?

Comment: You might want to check the C++11 threading model, and in particular its `std::atomic<bool>` class. This code is unnecessary complicated.

Comment: We don't have the std library, for some odd reason the company decided to remove it.

Comment: At that point you can't call it C++ anymore. The company should understand the cost of having its own proprietary language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The pointers are fine.

However, there is a good chance that static_thread_a_closed will not be read a second time because C doesn't, by default, know that static_thread_a_closed can change in the while loop.

Adding volatile keywords lets the compiler know that variables can be changed by interrupts/other threads/other processes, so that the variable must always be re-read. Otherwise, your while() might be optimized to while(1) or while(0).

```
static volatile bool     static_thread_a_closed = false;
static volatile bool     static_thread_b_closed = false;
static volatile bool     static_prog_closing = false;

static bool Get_Bool_Val(volatile bool* val)
```

Edit: After realizing I triggered some "Volatile Hostility," I should add that in this case, the volatiles will probably not make any difference in either case. In both cases, the while() is based on the return value of a function which the compiler *should* not optimize out, regardless if it wants to use the cached value of the static flags.

Comment: Good tip, thank you. In reality it is a while(true) loop, with the checks inside and a print to status message about what its waiting for, so I think this should be fine. But even so, this is good to keep in mind. Thank you!

Comment: This is wrong. `volatile` has nothing to do with getting thread semantics right. Any use of volatile when multi threading is wrong. `volatile` is only for access HW registers. It doesn't do anything for "re-reading" variables. See `http://cxx.isvolatileusefulwiththreads.com`.

Comment: @MikeVine thanks for the info, a webpage with no real info is kind of useless though..?

Comment: volatile object - ... within a single thread of execution,... This makes volatile objects suitable for communication with a signal handler, but not with another thread of execution, see std::memory_order). [link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)